# I don't see anything wrong, but the map will not appear (using gmaps.js from github)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the [GMaps.js in github](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/) but for some reason it is not working, I'm pretty sure I have typed it out right, if anybody could point me in the right direction thanks. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yae0Q.png actual photo in case it isn't big enough on here.)

[image: Broken Code]

Here is the new source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBi7e8AiTyqWiFt9vlbGqsAzGyRhVWqCsk&sensor=true"></script>
<script src="js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script>
/**
  * Basic Map
  */
$(document).ready(function(){
 var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#basic_map',
    lat: 51.5073346,
    lng: -0.1276831,
    zoom: 12,
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
        style : 'SMALL',
        position: 'TOP_LEFT'
    },
    panControl : false,
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="basic_map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You used "el", but i see in examplpes they use `div: '#map',` to show in which div map should appear, also you sure you got "#basic_map" div big enough to show anything? (width and height in css)

Comment: Sadly that did not fix it.

Comment: The map is loaded in your page but you are missing the height and that's why you don't see the map even if it is loaded. Specify the height inside the Gmap options or by CSS and the problem will be fixed. Kedor's answer below points the actual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you are probably missing the width and height of the div, you try show map in.

Here is working jsfiddle: [jsFiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk4gx/26/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#basic_map',
        lat: 51.5073346,
        lng: -0.1276831,
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px',
        zoom: 12,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOpt: {
            style: 'SMALL',
            position: 'TOP_LEFT'
        },
        panControl: false
    });
});
```

Added width and height to the code.
Or **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk4gx/28/)** you have the same result, with width and height in css. Not much difference.

Comment: +1 from me. The problem is that the div's height is missing. The map is loaded on the page but it is not visible since the height is not defined.

Comment: kinda inconsistent behavior from the plugin... but yeah, there it is

Answer (score 4):

(Please excuse my poor English)

I solved this problem by taking a look at the "gmaps.js"-file...

gmaps.js (v4.5.0) uses `getElementById`.

```
if (typeof(options.el) === 'string' || typeof(options.div) === 'string') {
      this.el = getElementById(container_id, options.context);
    } else {
      this.el = container_id;
    }
```

Conclusion:

1. gmaps.js doesn't care if you're using `div: 'basic_map'` or `el: 'basic_map'` -> both will work fine.
2. WRONG = `div: '#basic_map'`, CORRECT = `div: 'basic_map'`.
3. Specify the width and height of the `div` with some CSS

Refresh and be happy. :)

Answer (score 2):

i tested the code. maybe you should set the width & height of your div element.
you could use firebugs to check if the map is already created

change your div like this
`<div id="basic_map" style="height: 100px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">`

Answer (score 0):

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#basic_map',
        lat: 51.5073346,
        lng: -0.1276831,
        width: '500px',  --->You must add this
        height: '500px',---->And this in your map declaration
        zoom: 12,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOpt: {
            style: 'SMALL',
            position: 'TOP_LEFT'
        },
        panControl: false
    });
});
```

in your div:

```
<div id="basic_map"></div>
```

---

or you change the div id to "map" and create style:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #map {
         width: 700px;
          height: 500px;
          border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    }
  </style>
```

In your div :

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```